# First Word always gets deleted when printed

Tags: c++

I am completely new to C++ and I was trying to make a program which repeated the phrase you entered how many times you want but it doesn't print out the first word.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using std::string;
using std::cin;

int main(){
    std::string phrase;
    int i;
    int x;
    std::cout << "Enter the number of times will be printed:\n";
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cout << "Now enter the phrase you want to be repeated:\n";
    std::cin >> phrase;
    getline(std::cin,phrase);

    while (i < x) {
        std::cout << phrase << "\n";
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction)

Comment: it does not print the first word of the phrase or the first iteration of the phrase ?

Answer (score 3):

You read the first word into `phrase` with

```
std::cin >> phrase;
```

and then you overwrite the variable with the remaining words of the line with

```
getline(std::cin,phrase );
```

You can simply remove

```
std::cin >> phrase;
```

from the code.

The next problem is that

```
std::cin >> x;
```

only reads the number and not the newline. You have to ignore the newline with

```
std::cin.ignore();
```

before

```
getline(std::cin,phrase );
```

Comment: And you will need to add a `cin.ignore()` to clear the leftover newline?